# Require login before doing a action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Thank everyone read my topic. But i need your help !
I've got a problem with Asp.NET MVC Action.

In HomePage. I have a link redirect to an action call checkTicket(), but require login.

So, in checkTicket() method. I'm using following code to check permision

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  return View();
}
else
{
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

But in action Login of Account controller. How can i return back to checkTicket's View() ?

This is something i want.
HomePage (click) -> checkTicket (require) -> Login (return) -> checkTicket()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cookie that is set, letting you know that the user wants to checkticket but is not logged in:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return View();
}
    else
{
    //The cookie's name is UserSettings
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");

    //The subvalue of checkticket is = true
    myCookie["checkticket"] = "true";

    //The cookie expires 1 day from now
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);

    //Add the cookie to the response
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Then in your Login Action, check if the cookie exists like so:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    string userSettings;
    if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["checkticket"] != null)
    { 
        userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["checkticket"]; 
    }

    if(userSettings) { 
        //redirect to checkticket
    } else {
        // redirect to your normal view
    }
}
```

*Code courtesy of MSDN: [write cookie](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2F78c837bd(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&ei=RSzHU5jdKJKNyASxl4KYCg&usg=AFQjCNHb2NUBJYUP040NbyKAjIP8ktkjaw&sig2=Cg1UwPyLe4467QY0UU4_zw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.aWw), [read cookie](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fvstudio%2Fbd70eh18(v%3Dvs.100).aspx&ei=RSzHU5jdKJKNyASxl4KYCg&usg=AFQjCNHzNGP3ehvqh4YxKWFDar57u-Z18g&sig2=dBth-KHqlfRcr0PMPOtSFg&bvm=bv.71198958,d.aWw)

Comment: Thanks for your helping :)

nice day bro